# unable to set kafka properties in spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream kafka. I have set the properties for kafka as follows:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/x-java-object;type=com.example.demo.KafkaApplication.Message
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://172.16.165.26:8761/eureka/
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=10.6.22.20
#spring,cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=10.6.22.20
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=10.6.22.20:9092
#spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=example-consumer-1
spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount=1
spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=0
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.group=example-consumer-1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.consumer.instanceCount=1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.consumer.instanceIndex=0
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.consumer.resetOffsets=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.consumer.startOffset=earliest
```

the properties are being ineffective. kafka is taking an anonymous group instead of the given property. so was the case with startOffset

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and is fixed in the latest 1.3.x snapshot:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/7355ada4613ad50fe95430f1859d4ea65f004be1